# How to code a arrival generator with a varying intensity rate

Tags: events, simulation, stochastic

This is for a simulation model:

Most questions I've come about deal with how to code an generator with exponential arrival times.

But I'm currently stuck on how to program a generator where the arrival rate can change within a discrete event simulation.

In particular I'm stuck with the following case: my generator has an input port which accepts an arrival rate (double). If this rate change arrives exactly when an entity is generated, I can simply create the entity, update the rate parameter for the distribution and sample a new arrival time.

But what should I do when the generator at time t1 receives a new rate input event and is already scheduled to create an entity in the future t2 -

Should I
a) Abort the creation at t2 and schedule a new creation time using the new rate parameter
or
b) Just update the rate parameter, let the generator create the entity at t2, and then sample a new arrival time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is called "thinning," but requires you to know the global maximum arrival rate λ<sub>max</sub>.  Generate arrivals at rate λ<sub>max</sub>, but for each generated arrival at time t, only execute the arrival event with probability λ<sub>t</sub>/λ<sub>max</sub>. You can do this by generating a uniform(0,1) random number U for each potential arrival, and executing the arrival event if U ≤ λ<sub>t</sub>/λ<sub>max</sub>.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thinning is indeed correct. Yet what I struggle with is that I don't know when to do the thinning if a particular arrival time is already scheduled (that is, the generator was interrupted by an external rate change event). Should I cancel the arrival event and the use thinning with the new λt OR should I wait until the arrival event has happended and then use λt + thinning?

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate ... I want to drive an arrival process by an continuous derivative which forms it's arrival rate (derivative = arrival rate λ = units/time). Because they communicate on events, I need to ensure that this results in equivalent behaviour. This is because I'm worried that when the derivative is closely approximated (that is, lots of events) that no arrivals are being produced because of the generator constantly rescheduling itself according to a new arrival rate

Comment: @JackShade You cannot generate the next arrival based on the current instantaneous rate, because if that went to zero you'd never generate another arrival -- a rate of zero will yield an interarrival time of infinity.  With the thinning approach I described, arrivals will occur in proportion to the variations in the rate, whether those variations are continuous, piecewise linear, or something else entirely, and the arrival process will never get stuck.